# How to create an background activity in app inventor

Tags: background-process, app-inventor

I wanted to create an app in appinventor that would switch screen right/left depending on what side the phone is shaken while unlocked. But couldnt figure out:
a. how to make application run in background.
b. what property i am going for. Like what tells phone's screen to scroll left or right when finger slides across the screen. What method is called. I figured view class would have to do something with it. Having no java experience i couldn't make much sense out of sdk,refernce,resources etc.

Please help me out, i will give you credit for it.
Oh also i think i might have to include "activity starter" too.

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue for app inventor
http://code.google.com/p/app-inventor-for-android/issues/detail?id=32

star it to show you are interested

Answer (score 1):

The standard Application Inventor 2 website, as you surely know, is this one:

> http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/

However, there is another one, which allows using background threads ([services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)):

> http://services.appinventor.mit.edu/

It has a feature not available on the standard (*official*) AI2 website, the **Add Task** functionality, which allows adding tasks that will keep running even after a screen have been closed.

However, since it is an **unsupported** version, whose last release is dated from almost 1 year ago, I did not spent time making experiments, but this migh meet what you need:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The website will turn down, but worked like a charm before.
The whole concept was based on a Master Thesis: https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/100626/932752939-MIT.pdf;sequence=1

The last message from the site was something like: Google change the concept of background service architecture which cause the 'taks' concept to obsolate and prevent to work in the future.